# Can we expand the "How to look up a math symbol" to all kinds of symbols?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicates

Just today, [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40564/latex-numero-sign) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/symbol-for-cube) popped up that asked for symbols that aren't necessarily math-specific, but that still are answered by the famous duplicate top dog [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol).

Can we change the scope and wording of this question so that it applies to all kinds of symbols, perhaps with a slight focus on math symbols? The top answers refer to symbols in general, the lower-ranking are pretty math-specific.

The way it is, I just don't think [LaTeX: Numero sign ('№')](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40564/latex-numero-sign) really is a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol), because *№* isn't a math symbol; but it really *should* be a dupe.

(I proposed this in a comment to the question, but didn't get any reaction.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's very good to make a question more generic or even to a canonical question. Other questions, which would become duplicates this way (and possibly are less generic) can be closed, possibly answers merged.

This is a nice explanation:

- [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

In such cases, a good way is so submit an edit or an edit suggestion.

Comment: I've taken the bull by the horns and made the question more general.

Comment: @AlanMunn Great! And now we could start the recursion by applying the answer to the question...